# Find Next and Latest Date, With Conditions

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a list of asset IDs and service dates. I'd like to find the last service date and the next service date for a specific asset (each in their own column, with each row corresponding to an asset ID). The way I tried it was to use a formula like this:

```
{=IF(MIN(IF(Lists!$J$11:$J$31 = 'Action Overview'!A2,Lists!$K$11:$K$31))=0,NA(), MIN(IF(Lists!$J$11:$J$31 = 'Action Overview'!A2,Lists!$K$11:$K$31)))}
```

This would be to find the last service date, and I'd use 'MAX' in place of 'MIN' for the next service date. The problem is that my list contains dates before the last service date and after the next service date, so I wind up with dates far in the past and far into the future. I think the way to fix this would to be to use =TODAY() to get the current date, and use logic that says "maximum date for this asset less than or equal to current date" for the last service date and "minimum date for this asset greater than or equal to current date". I just don't have the familiarity with Excel's functions to make this work.

Any help you can provide with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Make it easier for us to help you by providing a sample of data that demonstrates the problem.  **Please** provide this as text or a downloadable file and **not** as a screenshot.  Much easier to copy/paste text, or open a file, than it is to convert a screenshot to Excel data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution myself. Here's what it came out to be for the last day in for service:

```
{=MAX(IF(Table4[Asset]='Action Overview'!A2,IF(Table4[In Shop]<=TODAY(),Table4[In Shop])))}
```

And here's what it was for next service date:

```
{=MIN(IF(Table4[Asset]=A2,IF(Table4[In Shop]>=TODAY(),Table4[In Shop])))}
```

Table4 is just the table I have the schedule set up in. You'd just select the range you have your values in if you weren't using a table.